# Runescape: Does the Helm of Devilry give the same damage boost as its predecessor the Mask of Dust?

Tags: runescape

In Runescape, the [Mask of Dust](https://runescape.wiki/w/Mask_of_Dust) says that it "The mask confers the same damage boost against dust devils (but only while on assignment) as the Slayer helmet."

When you get 700 kills it upgrades to the [Helm of Devilry](https://runescape.wiki/w/Helm_of_Devilry), does the damage boost carry over?

Comment: Not a definite answer, but the benefits of the Helm Devilry says *After the helm version has been unlocked, the player is free to switch between it and the mask version, as a cosmetic preference only – this does not restore the Slayer experience and double drop effects to the mask* - I'm assuming this means both the mask and helm provide two different benefit sets. The [Helm of Warping](http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Helm_of_Warping), being the same helm for abyssal demons, adds on *damage boost* as one of the lost benefits, it's possible the Helm of Devilry also loses the damage boost

Comment: But then if the damage boost was also gone, wouldn't it be mentioned there? That leads me to believe it *is* brought over.

Comment: That's why I didn't make it an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

All upgraded [Slayer Masks](https://runescape.wiki/w/Slayer_mask) lose their damage bonus benefit after reaching the milestone number of kills and being automatically upgraded.

Thus no, the damage bonus does not carry over. This can also be confirmed on the wiki by clicking each upgraded mask page and checking the benefits.